# Out of memory exception in Android when adding some image buttons

Tags: android

I have written a small Android project that shows some (image)buttons. It works fine on my phone ( Galaxy S ), but when I try to run it on emulator, it gives the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Please note, first activity, has 8 image buttons, and it gives out of memory exception. When I remove 3 buttons, it works fine. Actually, it works fine as long as scrollView is inivisble and If I add those 3 removed buttons ( so, scrollView is going to be visible ), it gives out of memory error. I think, this "out of memory" exception is not related to the number of (image) buttons, but is related to background image. Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/backgrounmobile" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top|bottom|right" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/centerlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top|bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/divan"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="@drawable/divanbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/boostan"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="@drawable/boostanbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/mavaez"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="@drawable/mavaezbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/hekayat"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="@drawable/hekayatbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/saadiname"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="@drawable/saadinamebtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/settings"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="@drawable/settingsbtn" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                    android:background="@drawable/aboutbtn" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: There's 4K+ questions with "bitmap size exceeds VM budget" on this site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your running low on memory, and the best way to remedy that will be to use less memory, loading smaller images will help a great deal here, and googles android team have been kind enough to put up a short description on how to do this :)

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually images size are 500*360 pixel, but their size is not larger than 80 KB. I think I should resize them.

Comment: The size on disk does not correspond to the memory footprint after loading the images into memory (and deflating them). You can typically assume that any image will use width * height * 4 bytes of memory once you load it into memory.

Comment: That link really helps.  For those who are reading this, read that!

Answer (score 3):

How big are the files that define the buttons (file size, not image dimensions)? It seems like those are just much too big. Android needs to load them all at once into main memory in order to display them.

For my app, all those files are in the 0.5~2kB range

Comment: I know, their size are maximum 80 KB. Is this why it gives exception?

Comment: That might very well be you problem then, they should be like Heiko pointed out be MUCH smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find this useful http://mobi-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-if-you-want-to-create-and.html